# WPF | It Is Possible To Use Default WPF Style On A TextBlock In HandyControl Window ? [KIND OF SOLVED]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, handycontrol

If i have this code, how can i indicate to the TextBlock in HandyControl Window to use the default WPF Style and not the HandyControl one ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

```
<hc:Window
    x:Class="TextTrimming_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextTrimming_Test"
        xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#181818">
    
    <TextBlock Text="I want to be the default WPF TextBlock !"/>
</hc:Window>
```

Comment: A `TextBlock` is not a `Control` so it cannot have a control template.  I don't know know what a HandyControl is.  If you want the `TextBlock` to have different default properties, give it a `Style`

Comment: @Joe Hi, sorry i used the wrong word, but yes i want to apply the default WPF Style on my TextBlock, how can i do that ? HandyControl is a UI Theme nuget package !

Comment: You could write a default style for `HandyControl` that has setters for the attached properties of the `TextElement` class.  Literally it would have Setters for things like `TextElement.FontSize`, `TextElement.FontWeight`, etc.  This would affect `TextBlock` s contained within.  However, it would likely affect *all* `TextBlock` s contained within which might not be what you want.  Actually you don't even need a default style.  You could first try just setting `TextElement.FontSize` on the `hc:Window` object and see if that has an effect

Comment: Wait a minute.  In your example, you show yourself explicitly declaring a `TextBlock`.  Why not just set the style yourself there?  If need be, you could declare a named style for `TextBlock` based upon the default one outside of the Window and then apply it by name.  You could even declare a resources section inside your Style for `hc:Window` that sets the default style *there*

Comment: @FrenchMan68: Try `Style="{x:Null}"`. If this doesn't work, you need to define a `Style` and set the `Style` property of the `TextBlock` to this one. Or modify whatever styles you are currently using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help guys, i was trying this method for solving a problem in another project with the same configuration (the original question is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73513094/wpf-how-do-i-use-textblock-texttrimming ), but set the style of the TextBlock don't works for this case i guess.

I was trying to see if by setting the style of the TextBlock it was gonna remove the TextTrimming problem... But thank you anyway ! :)